# re-sizing and re-centering a google map without access to a global variable "map"

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I have google maps implemented on my page and i want to be able to resize and recenter it After a particular event. Here is code i have found on the internet:

```
var center = map.getCenter();
google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
map.setCenter(center);
```

Now this is all cool but i dont have access to a "map" global. Instead i have been able to use a jquery selector to get the map-canvas DOM like so:

```
google.maps.event.trigger($("#map-canvas")[0], 'resize');
```

but using `$("#map-canvas")[0];` doesnt work when i try to call getCenter() and setCenter(). Any ideas why?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your map variable is an instance of google map object, but your `$("#map-canvas")[0]` is a DOM element, so you can't call any method because google won't recognize it.

In your case, it may just be a scope problem

Why don't you just put your map variable global and call it everywhere e.g:

```
var map; // my google map object

$(document).ready(function(){
  var center = map.getCenter();
  google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
  map.setCenter(center);
});
```

And then, whenever you call `map.getCenter();` it should return you the value (only if you already create the google object, obviously)